# Simple Java present value calculator is not working

Tags: java

I have not used java before and I am confused as to why a simple present value calculator I wrote is not working. The present value formula returns a super small number for some reason? See if you can spot my error:

```
// Import all utilities
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.*;

// Base class
public class Project2
{

   // Main function
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // Define variables
      double p = 0.0;
      double f = 0.0;
      double r = 0.0;
      double n = 0.0;
      String another = "Y";

      // Create a currency format
      DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");

      // Create a new instance of the scanner class
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Loop while another equals "Y"
      while(another.equals("Y"))
      {
         // Get future value
         System.out.println("Future value: ");
         f = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());

         // Get annual interest rate
         System.out.println("Annual interest rate: ");
         r = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());

         // Get Number of years
         System.out.println("Number of years: ");
         n = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());

         // Run method to find present value and display result
         p = presentValue(f, r, n);
         System.out.println("Present value: $" + p );

         // Ask if user wants to enter another
         System.out.println("Enter another?(Y/N) ");
         another = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
      }

   }

   public static double presentValue(double f, double r, double n)
   {
      // Do math and return result
      double p = f / Math.pow((1 + r), n);
      return p;
   }
}
```

Comment: "See if you can spot my error"  - it would be *far better* if you identified and isolated the part of code you believed to be causing your error.  We can't spot-check your code for you at will...

Comment: Making it smaller is what it will necessarily do right now because your presentValue math divides by a number larger than 1.

Comment: What is the problem? You say "it returns a super small value". What is is the expected value? What is the actual value? Are you getting some error? What is that error? If you answer these questions, chances are you'll unblock yourself.

Comment: I am betting he is inserting the interest rate in (%) instead of 0.xx :)

Comment: Could you please share the values of `r`, `n`, `f` and the "super small value"?

Comment: Missing bracket at :  `double p = f / Math.pow((1 + r), n);`. Typo..?

Comment: @Sage I assume the OP needs to multiply instead of dividing. `$1000 / 1.01 ^ 2 = $980.27` where `$1000 * 1.01 ^ 2 = $1020.1`.

Comment: @Radiodef, Nope, his formula for computing present value from  future value is correct. Though it is assumed that `r <= 1`

Comment: My bad. I am thinking future from present.

Comment: This question is getting upvote! how come ? well being inspired though :|

Comment: @Sage I bet you are right he is entering a percentage.

Comment: I am an idiot... Sage was right...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you enter the R as `% per annum` i.e. for e.g. `R = 4.3%`, you would want to modify the function as :

```
double p = f / (Math.pow((1 + (r/100.0)), n));
return p;
```

If this is not what you would want, you might want to enter the value of `R=4.3% p.a` as

`4.3/100 = 0.043` **and not** `4.3`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of future value Please take an input for Principal.

Your PresentValue Calculation Function will be like this. Try this function, hope you will get your perfect result

```
public double presentValue(double principal, double yearlyRate, double termYears)
{
    // Do math and return result
    double pValue = principal * (((1- Math.pow(1 + yearlyRate, -termYears))/ yearlyRate));
    return pValue;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Math.pow expects the first argument to be the base and the second the exponent. ( See [The Math javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) )

In your program the first argument is the power and the second is the base.

Change that to  double p = f / Math.pow(n, (1 + r)); and  I expect your program to run as expected

Comment: Uhhhh.. No it isn't. The `pow` function is used correctly. Check the javadoc. Kindly read it before you post it.

Answer (score -2):

Your program works fine. I just tested it.

```
Future value: 
100000
Annual interest rate: 
0.4
Number of years: 
20
Present value: $119.519642774552
Enter another?(Y/N) 
Y
Future value: 
100000
Annual interest rate: 
40
Number of years: 
20
Present value: $5.550381891760752E-28
Enter another?(Y/N)
```

You're entering the interest rate wrong probably.

If you want to enter an integer value, you can modify the formula:

```
double p = f / (Math.pow((1 + (r/100.0)), n));
```

This will result in:

```
Future value: 
100000
Annual interest rate: 
40
Number of years: 
20
Present value: $119.519642774552
Enter another?(Y/N)
```

Comment: Wrong. Check the javadoc again. The first argument is the base. The second one is the power.

Comment: Oh, so you want to take the interest to the power of a number of years?

Comment: If it compounds, yeah. If the interest is 0.01 then after the first year the value will be 1.01 and after the second year it will be 1.01 of that.

Comment: @dtgee : I guess that is what the formula says. I can't change the formula.